# How to add month to a date in european format in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date   Time   RH
29.03.2017 09:00:00 53.44
```

with many observations. I want to add a new column to my dataframe which shows the month of the date (ex: 20.03.2017 March) for the entire year. My dataframe goes from 29.03.2017 til 01.01.2018. I have tried it for a couple hours now and nothing seems to work, please help.

Comment: Most likely you information is a character string and not a date/time object.  First set is to convert from the character string using `as.Date` or `as.POSIXct`  once it is a date object or a datetime object you can then add or subtract from it.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. I however do not know what you mean (I'm very new to R). Could you maybe show me what the code would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your "Date" column into a date object using `as.Date()`

`df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")`

Then you can use format to extract the month such as:
`df$month <- format(df$Date, format = "%b")`

Alternatively you can use the Lubridate package

`library(lubridate)
df$month <- month(df$Date, label = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!!! This made me cry (almost). I have not worked with dates in R yet and I would constantly use %d-%m-%Y instead of the points in between. Many thanks & have a nice day!

Comment: Yes, the format should exactly match what is present in the character object. So for example,
`d1 <- "ABC Mar 21, 2018, DEF"`
`d2 <- as.Date(d1, format = "ABC %b %d, %Y, DEF")`